# Issues with font sizes on different dpis

Tags: android

I specify all font sizes in sp. The text looks good on several devices including Nexus 7, Galaxy S4 mini etc. However, on Galaxy S 3, the font is too large. Is this because the DPI of the S3 is so much more? If so, how do I adjust for this so that fonts display at relatively similar sizes?

Comment: Please see the link above. If a font with the same `sp` dimensions appears larger on one device than on another, the *Font Scaling is working properly*. 

On the S3, check Settings/Display/Font Size and verify that it's "Normal," not "Large." If you need your font size consistent, use `dp` instead of `sp` -- but only use that as a last resort. The reason font sizes can be scaled is to allow for users with poor eye-sight to make apps usable for them.

Comment: Have you defined different font sizes for different density?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DP/SP seems to be working properly. The larger font sizes I got was because of setting text sizes programmatically, using resource values which were already returned scaled - so essentially fonts were being double scaled. This could have been prevented by proper documentation by Android.

Answer (score 0):

On my project i use different "*dimens.xml*" file for every type of density folder, for example:

- values-mdpi
- values-hdpi
- values-xhdpi

dimens.xml has:

```
<!-- Text dimension for activity album preview -->
<dimen name="text_album_title">20sp</dimen>
<dimen name="text_album_author">18sp</dimen>
<dimen name="text_album_info">13sp</dimen>

<!-- Text dimension for row -->
<dimen name="text_track_title">16sp</dimen>
<dimen name="text_track_length">14sp</dimen>
```

And this is different for every file in folder. Is up to you to decide the size, you will see the difference between each dimension by using a layout with a TextView. Give it a try.

**EDIT**

I was totally wrong on this subject, thanks to Runloop and 323go.

Comment: Please don't give this a try. It defeats the purpose of `dp`/`sp` completely. Font sizes should be dependent on screen-size, not on density. If you provided different values by density, then your app would look different on, say, the old Nexus 7 and the new Nexus 7. @JaAd is clearly mistaken on how these values interact.

Comment: @323go if you say so. Can you provide an example by the way? How do you will solve Run Loop problem?

Comment: @JaAd, there is no "if you say so" -- this is well-documented. My comment on his question should solve his problem.

Comment: @323go As I stated in my question, just using dp/sp simply does not work for devices with very different densities. Get the devices I mentioned and test for yourself. Giving out answers which do not bear out in real life helps no one. BTW - user font size settings are the same on all test devices.

Comment: @RunLoop, compare your `dimens` files. Android is *designed* to handle density variations transparently, thus dp/dip and sp for text. Use any of the sample apps, set the text size to a fixed sp dimension and run it on all your devices -- compare the screens next to each other, or measure with a ruler. The text should be the same physical size from one device to the next. You either have rogue values in your dimens.xml, or you are confusing density and screen size.

Comment: @RunLoop i hope you will clarify this problem; i'm not stubborn, but i simply want to know how this will end.